# Is a phrase "You couldn't just miss the opportunity to do something?" valid?

Tags: grammar

Is a phrase "You **couldn't just miss** the opportunity to do something?" valid in English?

If not, what rules prohibit that?

UPD: the question is not regarding negation, sorry to misguide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the word-order of an indicative sentence ("You miss opportunity?") in a question is pretty common in spoken English.  The rising tone at the end and the context make it clear that you are asking not telling.

In written English, it might be better to phrase it in the ordinary way ("Couldn't you miss the opportunity") but there is nothing inherently incorrect in your way.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I have doubts about things that were always obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a rule, *per se*, but there are two valid idioms:

"You couldn't do *X*, could you?"

"You could do *X*, couldn't you?"

One has to be positive, and the other, negative.

Comment: I meant "couldn't *just miss*" part. I'll fix it now in question.

Comment: And yes, I didn't even realize there was a mistake in my original question